# ADT Bundle for Windows install issue

Tags: installation, bundle, adt

Using Windows XP 32-bit

I'm trying to install the Android SDK ADT Bundle for Windows
'adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522'
for Eclipse 4.2.2 in directory
c:\Program Files\Android SDK.

When extracting was initially getting 'Password Required on
org.eclipse.equinox.internal...'
Deleted everything and started over but now am getting 
'This folder already contains a file named
adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse'
and would I like to replace it.
I respond 'Yes to All' but the install keeps coming back
asking the same question and never finishing.

Any ideas out there?

Thanks

Comment: Did you got the solution? I am also facing same issue